# Can't Include static library GameAnalytics

Tags: c++, cmake, gameanalytics

I collected game analytics static library:

```
git clone https://github.com/GameAnalytics/GA-SDK-CPP.git
cd GA-SDK-CPP\build\cmake\gameanalytics\build
cmake --build . --config=Release
cmake --install. --config=Release
```

At this stage I have a file GameAnalytics.lib

Then I copied the file to the project and added cmake line

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE libs/GA-SDK-CPP/source/gameanalytics)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE GameAnalytics.lib)
```

I am including the lib:

```
#include "GameAnalytics.h"
```

But I have an error:

```
GameAnalytics.lib(GAUtilities.obj) : error LNK2019: ?????? ?? ????????????? ??????? ?????? "public: class Guid __cdecl GuidGenerator::newGuid(void)" (?newGuid@GuidGenerator@@QEAA?AVGuid@@XZ) ? ??????? "public: static void __cdecl gameanalytics::utilities::GAUtilities::generateUUID(char *)" (?generateUUID@GAUtilities@utilities@gameanalytics@@SAXPEAD@Z).
GameAnalytics.lib(GAHTTPApi.obj) : error LNK2019: ?????? ?? ????????????? ??????? ?????? curl_global_init ? ??????? "private: __cdecl gameanalytics::http::GAHTTPApi::GAHTTPApi(void)" (??0GAHTTPApi@http@gameanalytics@@AEAA@XZ).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you install the headers?  Where are you updating the search path for includes?

Comment: You probably need a `target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE folderWIthTheHeaders)`

Comment: Since you are using msvc are you sure you will never want to use debug mode? You started by compiling only the release configuration. This will be incompatible with debug mode.

Comment: @drescherjm I am compiling in release mode lib and project, it's fine